# How to upload file into webpage using OS file explorer?

Tags: html, python-3.x, selenium

I testing a webpage that allows me to import csv's into the page.

The webpage uses the button 'Import From File' to drop down a finder window (Mac osx) where I can select my file to upload. My selenium code has gotten me to this point.

I am not able to find the text or ID fields that are driving the upload process in the webpage.The HTML tag below is for the button, I think `'data-source'` is where file path goes but I can not use if for some reason:

```
<a class="ac_button blue ac_button large import_file_link" data-source="file" onclick="return false;"><span>Import From File</span></a>
```

code so far:

```
#click on 'import from file' button
imports = driver.find_element_by_link_text('Import From File')
imports.click()


#file upload
fileUpload = driver.find_element_by_id('data-source')
fileUpload.send_keys('/Users/bob/Desktop/test.csv')
```

What ID or text am I missing in the `'find_element_by'` that will help me upload my csv ?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Did you try `fileUpload = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//input[@type="file"]')`?

Comment: That worked! Question for you is how do I make the finder window go away after selecting my file?

Comment: What is the *finder window*? Do you mean file upload prompt like [this one](http://2.bp.blogspot.com/-lEZIGdCwdkg/TWfp3hvdzDI/AAAAAAAADo8/YCMq_gCqqvA/s640/Choose+file+to+upload.png)? Does it appears after `imports.click()`?

Comment: finder window is exactly the file upload prompt that you have shown for windows except for mac. It appears right after imports.click()

Comment: Just remove `imports` definition and click. Those lines are redundant - `fileUpload.send_keys()` will work even without those lines

Comment: When I comment out both lines for imports, the code completely stops after fileupload.send_keys(), with no change on the page. Is that what you mean by removing the definition?

Comment: Yes, I meant that only `fileUpload = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//input[@type="file"]')` and `fileUpload.send_keys('/Users/bob/Desktop/test.csv')` lines are required... Can you share page URL or it's not public page?

Comment: page URL is activecampaign.com, However you will need a login to access the page I am on.